# Modular dynamic based routing with wildcards

Tags: mvc, php5

I've created this router for my framework and wanted to get some feedback on if it's the most efficient way to search the routes.

The main router

```
public static function route($modules = true){
    $route = (isset($_GET['route']) && $_GET['route'] != '') ? trim($_GET['route'], '/') : '/';

    $parts = explode('/', $route);

    if($parts[0] == 'debug' && ENVIROMENT == 'development'){
        array_shift($parts);
        static::$debug = true;
    }

    unset($_GET['route']);

    if($route != '/' && count($parts) != 0){
        static::$routeParts = $parts;

        if($parts[0] == 'modules' && $modules){
            $path = null;

            $fullpath = md5('/'.implode('/', $parts));

            //exact match
            $pathFound = key_exists($fullpath, static::$routingTable);

            //if full path not found look for partial 
            if(!$pathFound){
                $elements = count($parts);// - 2;//parts after the module name
                $bits = $parts;

                if($elements > 0){
                    //array_pop($bits); //remove the final element - wildcard

                    $paths = array();
                    for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++){
                        $searchPath = '/'.implode('/', $bits).'/*';
                        $paths[] = $searchPath;
                        foreach(static::$routingTable as $rt){
                            if($searchPath == $rt['path']){
                                $pathFound = true;
                                $path = $rt;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if($pathFound)
                            break;
                        else
                            array_pop($bits);
                    }

                    /*if($pathFound !== true){
                        //match base module and send rest as params
                        $moduleSlug = $parts[1];
                        $fullpath = md5('/modules/'.$parts[1]);
                        $pathFound = key_exists($fullpath, static::$routingTable);
                        $path = static::$routingTable[$fullpath];
                    }*/
                }
                else{
                    $fullpath = md5('/'.implode('/', $parts).'/*');

                    $pathFound = key_exists($fullpath, static::$routingTable);
                    $path = static::$routingTable[$fullpath];
                }
            }
            else
                $path = static::$routingTable[$fullpath];


            array_shift($parts);
            array_shift($parts);
            if($pathFound){
                static::$view = 'view';
                static::$args['dir'] = $path['callback']['config']['directory'];
                static::$args['slug'] = $parts;
                $_GET['params'] = $parts;
                static::$args['module'] = true;
                static::$args['fullwidth'] = (isset($path['callback']['config']['fullwidth']) ? $path['callback']['config']['fullwidth'] : false);

                ModuleLoader::runModule($path);
            }
            else{
                //not ideal
                static::$view = '404';
                static::$args['fullwidth'] = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            static::$view = $parts[0];
            array_shift($parts);
            array_shift($parts);
            static::$args['slug'] = $parts;
            $_GET['params'] = $parts;
        }
    }
    else{
        //home page module
        static::$view = 'index';
        static::$args['fullwidth'] = true;
    }
    static::$routed = true;
}
```

Some examples routes added are which will all be pre-pended with site directory + '/modules/' :

```
/
/test
/test/
/test/*
```